# Error Mcrypt when hosting laravel 5 using XAMPP on OS X

Tags: laravel, xampp

I am trying to host Laravel 5 app without using `php artisan serve`, so I want to deploy my laravel app in XAMPP. But there is an error

```
MCrypt PHP extension not installed.
```

How can I instal php mcrypt extension in XAMPP on OSX ?

Comment: Hi, please see the help section for SO. I think this is the wrong page for this question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Sorry, I am new of stackoverflow, I do not know that I can not ask this type of questions in the stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to enable your mcrypt, open your .bash_profile by running:

```
vim ~/.bash_profile
```

…and paste the following line at the end:

```
export PATH="/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin:$PATH"
```

Save the file by pressing : and typing `wq` and then press enter to quit out.

Remember to reload the .bash_profile by running:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

And you're done!